# KeyboardAvoidingView Shrinks My TextInputs No Matter What

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, keyboard, padding

No matter what I do, KeyboardAvoidingView shrinks my TextInputs as much as it can instead of adding padding to the content above them and pushing them off the screen.

All I want is the normal behavior where my content is padded off the screen and nothing shrinks as is seen in the simplest tutorials using this component.  I've tried all the behaviors, and all kinds of permutations of view hierarchies. No matter what I do, it will shrink the inputs.

> ```
> <KeyboardAvoidingView style={Styles.containerView} behavior={'padding'}>
> <View style={Styles.topContainerView}>
>     <Image style={Styles.subLogo} source={require('../../../assets/images/app-icon.png')} />
>     <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', marginVertical: 10}}>
>         <Text style={Styles.subtext}>{subtext}</Text>
>     </View>
>         <TextInput 
>             style={Styles.textInput} 
>             onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({firstName: text})}
>             value={this.state.firstName}
>             />
>         <TextInput
>             style={Styles.textInput} 
>             onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({lastName: text})}
>             value={this.state.lastName}
>             placeholderText={'Last Name'}
>             />
>     <TextInput 
>         style={Styles.textInput} 
>         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
>         value={this.state.email}
>         placeholderText={'Enter Email'}
>         />
>     <TextInput 
>         style={Styles.textInput} 
>         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
>         value={this.state.password}
>         placeholderText={'Enter Password'}
>         secureTextEntry={true}
>         />
>
>         <TextInput 
>             style={Styles.textInput} 
>             onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({confirmPassword: text})}
>             value={this.state.confirmPassword}
>             placeholderText={'Confirm Password'}
>             secureTextEntry={true}
>             />
> </View>
> <View style={Styles.bottomContainerView}>
>     <Button buttonStyle={Styles.continueButton} text={"Continue"} onPress={continueAction} />
>     <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.cancelContainer} onPress={this.goBack}>
>         <Text style={Styles.cancelText}>{'Cancel'}</Text>
>     </TouchableOpacity>
> </View> 
> </KeyboardAvoidingView>
> ```

In my code above, the Image element and subtext below it will not budge. No padding will be added to them nor will they shrink. Instead, the TextInputs will all shrink.

I just want them to be pushed off the screen instead of the inputs shrinking.

I have also tried adding a ScrollView within the KeyboardAvoidingView that contains all the elements, and even given a hard-coded height to the inputs.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Nope, could not find a solution not matter what I tried. I ended up coding my own scrolling and got rid of KeyboardAvoidingView. I guess you have to do that. Pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks, I've put the scrollView's bottom padding into my state, then binding keyboard events to modify it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with RN 0.63.1 and Android 9, I encountered the same issue. Upon reading GitHub issues, using `KeyboardAvoidingView` was discouraged and instead setting this in my AndroidManifest.xml fixed it.

Default:

```
<activity
  ...
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>
```

Change it to:

```
<activity
  ...
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
>
```

I found setting this makes the padding work but it is still too close to the keyboard. I used `KeyboardAvoidingView` to add some padding between keyboard and text input.